# Remove duplicate array where key->value appears twice - leave just one array

Tags: php, arrays

Removing an array if there is a duplicate in inner array for example - As we see there is [0]['user'] and its 1, the same appears in the array [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNw6e.png), my desired array would only contain one of the arrays it doesn't matter which one - also would be nice if I would get a returned message that there were duplicates, the array length can vary from 1 to 10 for example. I tried some codes provided already here on stackoverflow for unique multidementional arrays but non seems to be working for me.

And this is the html method. The users can duplicate because of selection of the same user name

[image]

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["user"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["role"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["can_edit"]=>
    NULL
    ["can_read"]=>
    NULL
    ["can_execute"]=>
    NULL
    ["is_admin"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["user"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["role"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["can_edit"]=>
    NULL
    ["can_read"]=>
    NULL
    ["can_execute"]=>
    NULL
    ["is_admin"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Code used for the example output

```
foreach ($this->input->post() as $key => $value)
{
         if(preg_match("/^user.{1,2}$/",$key)>0) {
           $postvars[] = $key;
        }
        if(preg_match("/^user.{1,2}$/",$key)>0) {
           $postvalues[] = $value;
        }
}
$filterArray = array_combine($postvars, $postvalues);
function array_unique_multidimensional($input)
{
    $serialized = array_map('serialize', $input);
    $unique = array_unique($serialized);
    return array_intersect_key($input, $unique);
}

foreach (array_unique_multidimensional($postvars) as $key)
{
    preg_match("|\d+|", $key, $m);
    $user = $filterArray[$key];
    $role = $this->input->post('role'.$m[0]);
    $can_edit = $this->input->post('can_edit'.$m[0]);
    $can_read = $this->input->post('can_read'.$m[0]);
    $can_execute = $this->input->post('can_execute'.$m[0]);
    $is_admin = $this->input->post('is_admin'.$m[0]);

    $records[] = array('user' => $user,'role'=>$role,'can_edit'=>$can_edit,'can_read' =>$can_read,'can_execute' =>$can_execute,'is_admin'=>$is_admin);
}

var_dump($records);
```

Comment: Start with showing your code.

Comment: like `call_user_func_array("array_merge", $array)`?

Comment: oki done added some codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump(array_unique_multidimensional($records));
```